# Python text extraction from a video game screenshot

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, screenshot, python-tesseract

I am building a discord bot with discord.py for the video game Diablo 2. One of the functionalities requires the bot to extract the name and properties of items from Diablo 2 screenshots. I am currently using pytesseract for this but I am not getting sufficient results.

Example screenshot:
[image]

I cropped the part of the item (the code needs to do this automatically later) and got this after preprocessing (see code below):
[image]
[image]

That is the code for preprocessing and extracting the manually cropped image:

```
def grayscale(image):
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def threshold(image):
    return cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

def dilate(image):
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    return cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations = 1)

image = cv2.imread('item.png')

scale = 10 
w = int(image.shape[1] * scale)
h = int(image.shape[0] * scale)
dim = (w, h)
image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

image = grayscale(image)
image = threshold(image)
image = dilate(image)

custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%+'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=custom_config))
```

It gives me these results:

> sSPIRITWARD
>
> WARD
>
> ITamLavar66 Se a
>
> Daryusa4if Oe
>
> CHANCE Te BLece7a%
>
> DURABILITY Blep5
>
> REQUIREDSTRENGTHI76
>
> RaguinaDLavat66
>
> 6%CHANCETSCASTLEVEL8FADEWHENSTRUCE
>
> 926%PFASTERBLeckRATE
>
> 29%IMCREASEDCHANCEOFBLeckiING2
>
> Los t142%PNHANCEDDEFENSE a ALLRESISTANCES93i
>
> Ay eYCeGlLOABSERE
>
> ETHEREALCANNTBEREPAIRED

And I am unsure on how to proceed to get better results. The font and resolution are certainly difficult for OCR (you can see in the results how the OCR has problems with 5 and 6 especially). Here are some further pointers on the problem:

- I do have the Diablo 2 font (Exocet) so I might be able to train my own model (?)
- I do have list of all possible items and properties to further whitelist the results (however, I need the exact numbers for my bot's functionality)
- I also tried another lib (keras-ocr) but did not get better results

Answer (score 4):

I have a slightly improved solution

---

- 1. Resize the image, so each character can be seen clearly
- 2. Take each line one-by-one

---

| Preprocessed | Tesseract output |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | oo : SPIRIT WARD © ( |
| [image] | _WARD ' |
| [image] | Irem LeveL: 88 |
| [image] | DeFEeNs@: 41° |
| [image] | CHANCe Te@ BLeck: “73% |
| [image] | DURABILITY: 51 @F 61 |
| [image] | RE@UIRED STRENGTH: 176 |
| [image] | ReouireD LeveL: 68 ) |
| [image] | 6% CHANCE T® CAST LEVEL 8 FADE WHEN STRUCK. |
| [image] | 926% FasTER BLOCK RATE |
| [image] | 29% INCREASED CHANCE @F BLOCKING |
| [image] | 8h462% ENHANCED) DEFENSE ON |
| [image] | ALL RESISTANCES @3h |
| [image] | 9 COLD ABSORE |
| [image] | ETHEREAL [CANN@T BE REPAIRED) |

---

Comparison

| Current result | OP's result |
| --- | --- |
| oo : SPIRIT WARD © ( | sSPIRITWARD |
| _WARD ' | WARD |
| Irem LeveL: 88 | ITamLavar66 Se a |
| DeFEeNs@: 41° | Daryusa4if Oe |
| CHANCe Te@ BLeck: “73% | CHANCE Te BLece7a% |
| DURABILITY: 51 @F 61 | DURABILITY Blep5 |
| RE@UIRED STRENGTH: 176 | REQUIREDSTRENGTHI76 |
| ReouireD LeveL: 68 ) | RaguinaDLavat66 |
| 6% CHANCE T® CAST LEVEL 8 FADE WHEN STRUCK. | 6%CHANCETSCASTLEVEL8FADEWHENSTRUCE |
| 926% FasTER BLOCK RATE | 926%PFASTERBLeckRATE |
| 29% INCREASED CHANCE @F BLOCKING | 29%IMCREASEDCHANCEOFBLeckiING2 |
| 8h462% ENHANCED) DEFENSE ON | Los t142%PNHANCEDDEFENSE a ALLRESISTANCES93i |
| ALL RESISTANCES @3h | Ay eYCeGlLOABSERE |
| 9 COLD ABSORE | ? |
| ETHEREAL [CANN@T BE REPAIRED) | ETHEREALCANNTBEREPAIRED |

I made a slight changes in the processing.

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("YKEyQ.png")
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
img = cv2.resize(img, (w*3, h*3))
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]

s_idx = 0
e_idx = int(h/15)

for i, _ in enumerate(range(0, 15)):
    gry_crp = gry[s_idx:e_idx, 0:w]
    thr = cv2.threshold(gry_crp, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    thr = cv2.dilate(thr, None, iterations=1)
    cv2.imwrite("/Users/ahx/Desktop/res{}.png".format(i), thr)
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 6")
    print(txt)
    s_idx = e_idx
    e_idx = s_idx + int(h/15)
    cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```